# Mongoexport DocumentDB clusters to S3 Bucket

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, mongoexport, aws-documentdb

I have two mongodb cluster - want to export data. 
I am using EC2 instance to login to DocumentDB cluster and use mongoexport to get all the documents in JSON format.
Problem:
Number of records are more than 2 Billion and mongoexport will create one single file with all records.

Any suggestions on how 
1. mongoexport all data to multiple files 
2. write all exported data directly to s3 bucket instead of first writing to EC2 and then using aws s3 cp/ sync to upload it to s3.

Looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-to-s3 - too old to use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-dump-s3-2 - it takes mongodump, I want data in Json format.